# How to coverage run django-admin.py test?

Tags: django, code-coverage, travis-ci

I'm running tests for a pluggable app using

```
PYTHONPATH=..:$PYTHONPATH django-admin.py test --settings=...
```

i.e. I don't have any `manage.py` in the VCS. How do I run this on coverage? When `manage.py` exists, this is documented in Django docs as

```
 PYTHONPATH=..:$PYTHONPATH coverage run manage.py test --settings=...
```

but I was trying to avoid creating one just for running the coverage. This is useful e.g. `.travis.yml`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to use `which django-admin.py` with "`":

```
PYTHONPATH=..:$PYTHONPATH coverage run `which django-admin.py` test tests.query.tests.QueryTestCase.test_execute --settings=tests.settings_test
```